# When $Res(f(z); z_0) = 0$, is $f$ analytic at $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $Res(f(z); z_0) = 0$, does that mean that $f$ is analytic at $z_0$? Further, does it mean that $f$ has a continuous antiderivative around $z_0$?

The above is a homework question I have, but I am rather shaky with the fundamentals and would like to have any misunderstandings corrected.

I've established that I'm very misguided. What to consider, maybe in terms of theorems or definitions I should look at again?

Comment: No. The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion, but doesn't determine higher terms. Consider $1/z^2$ or $1 / (z \sin z)$.

Comment: Right, so then is this a case of not enough information? It seems to me that you cannot classify the type of singularity, so what more is there to infer from$ Res(z;z_0)=0$?

Comment: It does tell you that you can integrate your function in a loop around the point and get zero.  Usually when there's a pole, you can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the residue at $z_0$ is $0$, there is indeed a continuous antiderivative in a deleted neighbourhood of $z_0$.  That is, the Laurent series $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$$ (converging for $0 < |z-z_0| < r$, for some $r > 0$) has $a_{-1} = 0$, and an antiderivative is $$F(z) = \sum_{n \ne -1} \frac{a_n}{n+1} (z-z_0)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Does it also follow that $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, with

$f'(z) = \sum_{n \ne -1} na_n (z-z_0)^{n-1} $ ?

Comment: No, not if there are nonzero $a_n$ for $n < 0$.

Comment: Could you please explain why that is the case?

Comment: Because if it were analytic, the Laurent series would be a Taylor series.